# Recursive function inside loop analysis using recursive techniques

Tags: analysis, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

The question wants me to analysis the performance of the code using recursive techniques.

I am still new to analysis of algorithms. I know how to analyze loops and recursion separately but, in this code the recursive method is called inside a loop and I don't get how to start.

Should I analyze the loops first using for example summation technique then analyze the recursive method or should I ignore the loop and focus on the recursive method.

For the recursive method, should I analyze it assuming only the worst case input for $B$ and $i \to$ analyze for input $i = n-2$ as this is the $\max i$?

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Qlh.png)